# how to create a collection from two collections with laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, collections

I display the results of two collections with foreach as shown below but I tried several ways to create a new collection that can't be used for the third foreach

```
$users = User::with('absen')->get();
$period = CarbonPeriod::create('2020-11-25','2020-11-30');
foreach ($period as $date) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
      echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
      echo "-->";
      echo $user->nama;
      echo "-->";
      foreach ($user->absen as $abse) {
          if ($abse->created_at->format('Y-m-d') == $date->format('Y-m-d')) {
            echo $abse->masuk;
            echo "-->";
            echo $abse->keluar;
            echo "\n";
          }
       }
       echo "<br />";
    }
  }
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTR3.png)

Comment: your question is quite unclear. what do you mean by collection?? update your question with more detail like current behavior and expected result.

Comment: i want to create a new collection with the following result, but i can only display via foreach https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBTR3.png

Comment: what is collection here?? you mean [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) ??

Comment: yes laravel collection, can you help me to create a new collection with a format like in the image?
in advance thank you very much